# Applied Dpi in Registry

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, resolution, dpi, high-dpi

While searching the Windows registry for a setting mentioned in a previous question, I found a whole bunch of settings that were of interest to me in the following registry key:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
```

One of those settings is Applied DPI Reg_DWord 0x00000060 (96)

I know that DPI(Dots Per Inch) & PPI(Pixels Per Inch) Are two different terms,
One for printing & one for Monitors and Tvs, But they are essentially the same. I would like to know how I can Match the setting in Windows reistry, to that of my monitor currently

My Monitor Has a pixel density of 108.79 PPI in the registry this is set to 96, so its not displaying at the full capacity that it could
The following document has some interesting info But it is mainly based upon C++ Programming although it does mention a few Registry Keys.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/_hidpi

& Another Article Found here, But it only really mentions Scaling

Not DPI : https://forum.rainmeter.net/viewtopic.php?t=31395

Just to be clear, I do not wish to change the Scaling as this only adjusts how big Icons, text and other Items Display on the screen. It does not actually change the Pixel density Can I match the Value 96 to 108.79 or round it up to 108/109? Has anyone else adjusted this setting and if so What were the results.?

**Update** Just Changed its decimal Value to 108 & on Restart windows has reverted it back to is original value of 96, So not sure if there any other option to increase this value. Maybe Have to change both its decimal value & the other value at the same time to match, but i'll have to try.